# Yolov8 unable to translate via ONNX to opencv DNN

Tags: java, opencv, yolov8

I am trying to use a dnn opencv module to render an onnx model. However, it keeps giving me an error:

```
CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.7.0-dev) /home/ci/opencv/modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp:1073: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'handleNode'
Node [Reshape@ai.onnx]:(onnx_node!/model.22/dfl/Reshape) parse error: OpenCV(4.7.0-dev) /home/ci/opencv/modules/dnn/src/layers/reshape_layer.cpp:109: error: (-215:Assertion failed) total(srcShape, srcRange.start, srcRange.end) == maskTotal in function 'computeShapeByReshapeMask'
]
    at org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromONNX_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromONNX(Dnn.java:508)
    at org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode.vision.DeepNeuralNetworkProcessor.(DeepNeuralNetworkProcessor.java:59)
    at org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode.vision.OnnxPipeline.(OnnxPipeline.java:13)
    at org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode.vision.AIDetectThread.start(AIDetectThread.java:25)
    at org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode.vision.OnnxTestImplementation.init(OnnxTestImplementation.java:26)
    at com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.OpMode.internalRunOpMode(OpMode.java:181)
    at com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.OpModeInternal.lambda$internalInit$1$com-qualcomm-robotcore-eventloop-opmode-OpModeInternal(OpModeInternal.java:180)
    at com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.OpModeInternal$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(D8$$SyntheticClass)
    at com.qualcomm.robotcore.util.ThreadPool.logThreadLifeCycle(ThreadPool.java:737)
    at com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.OpModeInternal.lambda$internalInit$2$com-qualcomm-robotcore-eventloop-opmode-OpModeInternal(OpModeInternal.java:178)
    at com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.OpModeInternal$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(D8$$SyntheticClass)
```

I have tried both simplifying and setting the input and ouput frames to the same resolution. Neither have even changed the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.